# Javascript is not working in blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger

```
<script src='http://www.tamiln.tk/index.php?page=evb' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

this share button working in local 
when i put into blogger it's not working.

If anyone know about that issue please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the Layout tab, click the "Add a Page Element" option and select the "HTML/Javascript" sub-option.

See the [Layout Guide](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/43708?hl=en) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Connor J 
you are right but you can also put **script** in main code
for it go to Themes > Edit Html and put your **script** exact above `</body>` , press **ctrl + f** for find `</body>`.